# Fail building CGAL with cmake on windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, cgal

the error code:

```
C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\build>cmake ..
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19043.
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:9 (cmake_minimum_required):     
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell  
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.   


CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:12 (cmake_policy):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell  
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.   


CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:20 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0042 will be removed from a future version 
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all       
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under 
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW  
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


== Setting paths ==
-- Build CGAL from release in directory CGAL-4.8.1
-- Packagenames: CGAL-4.8.1
== Setting paths (DONE) ==

== Generate version files ==
-- CGAL_MAJOR_VERSION=4
-- CGAL_MINOR_VERSION=8
-- CGAL_BUGFIX_VERSION=1
-- CGAL_SONAME_VERSION=11
-- CGAL_SOVERSION     =11.0.2
-- CGAL_REFERENCE_CACHE_DIR=
-- Building shared libraries
-- Visual Leak Detector (VLD) is not found.
-- Targetting Visual Studio 16 2019
-- Target build enviroment supports auto-linking
-- Using VC14 compiler.
-- Generator uses intermediate configuration directory: $(Configuration)
-- USING CMake version: 3.24.0
-- System: Windows
== Generate version files (DONE) ==

== Set up flags ==
-- Build type: Release
-- USING CXXFLAGS = '/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /fp:strict /fp:except- /wd4503 /bigobj /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG'
-- USING LDFLAGS = '/machine:x64 /INCREMENTAL:NO'
== Set up flags (DONE) ==

== Detect external libraries ==
-- External libraries supported: GMP;MPFR;ZLIB;OpenGL;LEDA;MPFI;RS;RS3;OpenNL;Eigen3;BLAS;LAPACK;QGLViewer;ESBTL;Coin3D;NTL;IPE
-- Preconfiguring library: GMP ...
-- GMP has been preconfigured:
--   UseGMP-file:
--   GMP include:      C:/dev/CGAL-4.8.1/auxiliary/gmp/include
--   GMP libraries:    C:/dev/CGAL-4.8.1/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libgmp-10.lib
--   GMP definitions:
-- USING GMP_VERSION = '5.0.1'
-- Preconfiguring library: MPFR ...
-- MPFR has been preconfigured:
--   UseMPFR-file:
--   MPFR include:      C:/dev/CGAL-4.8.1/auxiliary/gmp/include
--   MPFR libraries:    C:/dev/CGAL-4.8.1/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libmpfr-4.lib
--   MPFR definitions:
-- USING MPFR_VERSION = '3.0.0'
-- Boost include:     D:/geometry_lib/boost_1_61_0
-- Boost libraries:   
-- Boost definitions:
-- USING BOOST_VERSION = '1.61.0'
== Detect external libraries (DONE) ==

== Write compiler_config.h ==
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_BOOST_VARIANT_SWAP_BUG - Failed
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_DENORMALS_COMPILE_BUG - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_FPU_ROUNDING_MODE_UNWINDING_VC_BUG - Failed
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_IEEE_754_BUG - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_ISTREAM_INT_BUG - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_MATCHING_BUG_5 - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_MATCHING_BUG_6 - Failed
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_MATCHING_BUG_7 - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_MATCHING_BUG_8 - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NESTED_CLASS_FRIEND_DECLARATION_BUG - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NO_LIMITS - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NO_NEXTAFTER - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NO_STL - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NUMERIC_LIMITS_BUG - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_OUTOFLINE_MEMBER_DEFINITION_BUG - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_TEMPLATE_IN_DEFAULT_PARAMETER_BUG - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_TYPENAME_BEFORE_DEFAULT_ARGUMENT_BUG - Success
-- Performing Test CGAL_CFG_USING_BASE_MEMBER_BUG_2 - Success
== Write compiler_config.h (DONE) ==

== Generating build files ==
Configuring libCGAL
-- Requested component: MPFR
-- Requested component: GMP
libCGAL is configured
-- Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_Core' detected
Configuring libCGAL_Core
-- Requested component: MPFR
-- Requested component: GMP
libCGAL_Core is configured
-- Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_ImageIO' detected
Configuring libCGAL_ImageIO
-- OpenGL include:     
-- OpenGL libraries:   opengl32;glu32
-- WARNING: ZLIB found but could not compile print_ZLIB_version.cpp:
-- ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR=C:/msys64/mingw64/include
-- ZLIB_LIBRARIES=C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libz.dll.a
-- ZLIB_LIBRARIES_DIR=
-- Change Dir: C:/dev/CGAL-4.8.1/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.2+f32259642 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30145 for x64
  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
  print_ZLIB_version.cpp
  cl /c /IC:\msys64\mingw64\include /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D _MBCS /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D 
_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:strict /fp:except- /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR /Fo"cmTC_88d6d.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_88d6d.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /external:W3 /Gd /TP /wd4503 /errorReport:queue  /bigobj "C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\config\support\print_ZLIB_version.cpp"
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime.h(61,26): warning C4083: expected ')'; found identifier '_VCRUNTIME_DISABLED_WARNINGS' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime.h(111,1): warning C4005: '_CRT_STRINGIZE': macro redefinition [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\_mingw.h(293): message : see previous definition of '_CRT_STRINGIZE' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime.h(114,1): warning C4005: '_CRT_WIDE': macro redefinition [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\_mingw.h(298): message : see previous definition of '_CRT_WIDE' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime.h(155,1): warning C4005: '__CRTDECL': macro redefinition [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\_mingw.h(405): message : see previous definition of '__CRTDECL' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime.h(310,1): warning C4005: '_CRT_DEPRECATE_TEXT': macro redefinition [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\_mingw.h(356): message : see previous definition of '_CRT_DEPRECATE_TEXT' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime.h(351,51): error C2065: 'uintptr_t': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime.h(351,61): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_StackCookie' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime.h(352,67): error C2065: 'uintptr_t': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime.h(352,77): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_StackCookie' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime.h(356,35): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime.h(356,18): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier '__security_cookie' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\corecrt.h(75,53): error C2378: 'uintptr_t': redefinition; symbol cannot be overloaded with a typedef [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vcruntime.h(356): message : see declaration of 'uintptr_t' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\yvals.h(13,1): warning C4005: '_CPPLIB_VER': macro redefinition [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\yvals_core.h(556): message : see previous definition of '_CPPLIB_VER' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(209,5): error C2065: '__asm__': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(209,13): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier '__volatile__' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(209,35): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before ':' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(209,13): error C3861: '__volatile__': identifier not found [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(209,35): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before ':' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(209,35): error C2059: syntax error: ':' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]        
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(209,57): error C2059: syntax error: ')' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]        
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(220,5): error C2065: '__asm__': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(220,13): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier '__volatile__' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(220,35): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before ':' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(220,13): error C3861: '__volatile__': identifier not found [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(220,35): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before ':' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(220,35): error C2059: syntax error: ':' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]        
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(220,57): error C2059: syntax error: ')' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]        
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(231,5): error C2065: '__asm__': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(231,13): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier '__volatile__' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(231,35): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before ':' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(231,13): error C3861: '__volatile__': identifier not found [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(231,35): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before ':' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(231,35): error C2059: syntax error: ':' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]        
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(231,57): error C2059: syntax error: ')' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]        
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(1157,7): error C2065: '__asm__': undeclared identifier [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(1157,15): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier '__volatile__' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(1158,11): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before ':' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(1157,15): error C3861: '__volatile__': identifier not found [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(1158,11): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before ':' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(1158,11): error C2059: syntax error: ':' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]       
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\math.h(1158,45): error C2059: syntax error: ')' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]       
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdlib.h(148,115): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'uintptr_t' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdlib.h(388,16): error C2059: syntax error: '__declspec(nothrow)' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdlib.h(389,16): error C2059: syntax error: '__declspec(nothrow)' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdlib.h(391,16): error C2059: syntax error: '__declspec(nothrow)' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdlib.h(396,27): error C2144: syntax error: 'int' should be preceded by ';' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdlib.h(396,50): warning C4091: '__declspec(noreturn)': ignored on left of 'int' when no variable is declared [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdlib.h(398,54): error C2381: '_Exit': redefinition; 'noreturn' differs [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdlib.h(396): message : see declaration of '_Exit' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]   
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdlib.h(399,6): error C3861: '_exit': identifier not found [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdlib.h(405,16): error C2059: syntax error: '__declspec(noreturn)' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdlib.h(499,18): error C2059: syntax error: '__declspec(nothrow)' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdlib.h(500,17): error C2059: syntax error: '__declspec(nothrow)' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdlib.h(502,23): error C2059: syntax error: '__declspec(nothrow)' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdlib.h(505,25): error C2059: syntax error: '__declspec(nothrow)' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdlib.h(683,70): error C2144: syntax error: 'int' should be preceded by ';' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdlib.h(683,95): warning C4091: '': ignored on left of 'int' when no variable is declared [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdlib.h(685,49): error C2144: syntax error: 'int' should be preceded by ';' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdlib.h(685,74): warning C4091: '': ignored on left of 'int' when no variable is declared [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdlib.h(686,56): error C2144: syntax error: 'int' should be preceded by ';' [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\stdlib.h(686,81): warning C4091: '': ignored on left of 'int' when no variable is declared [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\malloc.h(82,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mm_malloc.h': No such file or directory [C:\dev\CGAL-4.8.1\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_88d6d.vcxproj]


-- USING ZLIB_VERSION = 'unknown'
-- Requested component: MPFR
-- Requested component: GMP
libCGAL_ImageIO is configured
-- Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_Qt5' detected
Configuring libCGAL_Qt5
CMake Deprecation Warning at src/CGAL_Qt5/CMakeLists.txt:4 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0043 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


-- libCGAL_Qt5 is missing the dependencies: Qt5OpenGL Qt5Svg Qt5 cannot be configured.
-- Sources for CGAL component libraries 'CGAL_Core;CGAL_ImageIO;CGAL_Qt5' detected
== Generating build files (DONE) ==

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/dev/CGAL-4.8.1
```

First, please forgive my poor English, thx guys.

I install the CGAL lib through using the `CGAL-4.8.1-Setup.exe` got from github and following the step on the [CGAM manual](https://doc.cgal.org/4.8.1/Manual/installation.html)

I want to install the lib and get the dynamic lib with suffix `.dll`, but something gets wrong when I use `cmake ..`, and it seems like I could not solve them by myself.

I already install gmp and mpfr and boost, and also add their directory into PATH, or as system variable, so I don't know what wrong with it.I can't get a makefile through using `cmake ..` in the dir build.

My aim is to get the dynamic lib `CGAL-vc140-mt-gd-4.8.1.dll`

Comment: Looks like interference between GCC and MSVC. Which of the two do you prefer? Do you actually want to build Cgal yourself, or a prebuilt one will do?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I use MSVC. I just install the CGAL using `CGAL-4.8.1-Setup.exe`, after that , I found that it lacked the dynamic lib I needed, so I read the `INSTALL.md` in the CGAL root directory and follow what it write to install the CGAL using cmake. I just think If I install the lib following the `INSTALL.md`, I will get the dynamic lib I want.

Comment: Was MSYS2 somehow involved in this? If yes, repeat without using it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thank you guys.After removing MSYS2, it works.

Comment: Removing it shouldn't be necessary, simply not using it when running CMake should be enough (and possibly removing it from the PATH). But if it works, it works...

Comment: hahaha, I am so foolish. I forget I could remove it from the PATH. it may sound funny. I just begin to learn how to use cmake, so I don't use it very well. And the MSYS2 will rarely be used in my work, so it's the easiest way for me to repair. Anyway, thank you guys.

Comment: CGAL is header only now, there is no dll anymore.

Comment: @MarcGlisse yes, but the version 4.8.1 still have to build dll.